# Compile error ruby eventmachine for OpenWRT Barrier Breaker errors with "error: size of array '...' is negative"

Tags: ruby, eventmachine, openwrt, ruby-2.2

I have embarked on creating a package of Ruby 2.2 with Event Machine for OpenWRT Barrier Breaker.  The makefile for the eventmachine package can be seen here: https://github.com/DaKaZ/ruby-openwrt/blob/master/packages/ruby-eventmachine/Makefile

I was able to successfully use the Ruby 2.2 implementation from the trunk of feeds/packages and am running OpenWRT Barrier Breaker with Ruby 2.2 on my router, but... eventmachine is throwing the following error when it builds:

```
In file included from /Volumes/OpenWrt/barrier_breaker/staging_dir/host/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h:33:0,
             from rubymain.cpp:26:
/Volumes/OpenWrt/barrier_breaker/staging_dir/host/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:107:73: error: size of array 'ruby_check_sizeof_long' is negative
 typedef char ruby_check_sizeof_long[SIZEOF_LONG == sizeof(long) ? 1 : -1];
                                                                         ^
/Volumes/OpenWrt/barrier_breaker/staging_dir/host/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:111:76: error: size of array 'ruby_check_sizeof_voidp' is negative
 typedef char ruby_check_sizeof_voidp[SIZEOF_VOIDP == sizeof(void*) ? 1 : -1];
                                                                            ^
In file included from /Volumes/OpenWrt/barrier_breaker/staging_dir/host/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:35:0,
                 from /Volumes/OpenWrt/barrier_breaker/staging_dir/host/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1710,
                 from /Volumes/OpenWrt/barrier_breaker/staging_dir/host/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from rubymain.cpp:26:
/Volumes/OpenWrt/barrier_breaker/staging_dir/host/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/st.h:52:93: error: size of array 'st_check_for_sizeof_st_index_t' is negative
 typedef char st_check_for_sizeof_st_index_t[SIZEOF_VOIDP == (int)sizeof(st_index_t) ? 1 : -1];
                                                                                             ^
make[4]: *** [rubymain.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [/Volumes/OpenWrt/barrier_breaker/build_dir/target-mipsel_74kc+dsp2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/linux-brcm47xx_mips74k/ruby-eventmachine-1.0.7/.built] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/Volumes/OpenWrt/barrier_breaker/feeds/rubyopenwrt/packages/ruby-eventmachine'
make[2]: *** [package/feeds/rubyopenwrt/ruby-eventmachine/compile] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/Volumes/OpenWrt/barrier_breaker'
make[1]: *** [/Volumes/OpenWrt/barrier_breaker/staging_dir/target-mipsel_74kc+dsp2_uClibc-0.9.33.2/stamp/.package_compile] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/Volumes/OpenWrt/barrier_breaker'
make: *** [world] Error 2
```

This appears to be an error in the HOST version of ruby but I can't figure out how to correctly use the cross compiled version to build eventmachine.  Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested - I was able to build and run event machine and it works great, but ONLY with a custom Makefile - I could never get the auto generated files to run correctly.  Here is that Makefile.  I use a simple script to setup the build properly:

```
echo "[update feeds]"
./scripts/feeds update -a

echo "[install packages from rubyopenwrt feed]"
./scripts/feeds install -a -p rubyopenwrt

echo "[install customized ruby-eventmachine makefile]"
cp em-build-works/Makefile feeds/rubyopenwrt/packages/ruby-eventmachine
```

Here is the working Makefile:

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk
include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/kernel.mk


RUBY_PKG_LIBVER:=2.2

PKG_NAME:=ruby-eventmachine
PKG_SHORT_NAME:=eventmachine
PKG_RELEASE:=1
PKG_LIBVER:=1.0.7
PKG_REV:=6dbdb97bada05d33a1f0d469a49d8c46ac2e77d0
PKG_VERSION:=$(PKG_LIBVER)

PKG_SOURCE:=$(PKG_NAME).tar.gz
PKG_SOURCE_URL:=git://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git
PKG_SOURCE_VERSION:=$(PKG_REV)
PKG_SOURCE_SUBDIR:=$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION)
PKG_SOURCE_PROTO:=git

PKG_BUILD_DEPENDS:=
PKG_BUILD_PARALLEL:=1

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/ruby-eventmachine
  SUBMENU:=Ruby
  SECTION:=lang
  CATEGORY:=Languages
  DEPENDS:=+ruby-socket +libstdcpp +libc +libgcc +libssl +libcrypto
  TITLE:=Ruby eventmachine gem
endef

RUBY:= \
    $(STAGING_DIR_HOST)/bin/ruby -I $(STAGING_DIR_HOST)/share/ri \


define Package/ruby-eventmachine/description
 This package contains the ruby eventmachine gem.
endef

define Build/Configure/eventmachine
    (cd $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/ext; \
        $(RUBY) extconf.rb; \
    );
endef

define Build/Compile/eventmachine
    $(MAKE_VARS) \
    $(MAKE) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/ext \
        $(MAKE_FLAGS) \
        $(1);
    $(CP) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/ext/*.so $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/lib/
endef

define Build/Configure/fastfilereader
    (cd $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/ext/fastfilereader; \
        $(RUBY) extconf.rb; \
    );
endef

define Build/Compile/fastfilereader
    $(MAKE_VARS) \
    $(MAKE) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/ext/fastfilereader \
        $(MAKE_FLAGS) \
        $(1);
    $(CP) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/ext/fastfilereader/*.so $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/lib/
endef

define Build/Configure
    $(call Build/Configure/eventmachine)
    $(call Build/Configure/fastfilereader)
endef

# hack Makefiles here
define Build/Compile
    $(SED) 's/-fstack-protector//' $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/ext/fastfilereader/Makefile
    $(SED) '17s/host.*/target-mips-rlx5281-linux\/usr\/include\/ruby-2.2\/mips-linux-gnu/' $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/ext/fastfilereader/Makefile
    $(call Build/Compile/fastfilereader)
    $(SED) 's/-fstack-protector//' $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/ext/Makefile
    $(SED) '17s/host.*/target-mips-rlx5281-linux\/usr\/include\/ruby-2.2\/mips-linux-gnu/' $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/ext/Makefile
    $(call Build/Compile/eventmachine)
endef

define Package/ruby-eventmachine/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/lib/ruby/$(RUBY_PKG_LIBVER)/mips-linux-gnu
    $(CP) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/lib/eventmachine.rb $(1)/usr/lib/ruby/$(RUBY_PKG_LIBVER)/
    $(CP) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/lib/em $(1)/usr/lib/ruby/$(RUBY_PKG_LIBVER)/
    $(CP) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/lib/*.so $(1)/usr/lib/ruby/$(RUBY_PKG_LIBVER)/mips-linux-gnu
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,ruby-eventmachine,+libopenssl))
```